# Can't rate songs with Genius Mixes

Tags: itunes

When playing a Genius Mix in Itunes 9, certain features don't seem to be working. For example the "Ctrl+L" shortcut doesn't work and File->Rating doesn't work either. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best workaround I've found are to either use the Genius icon in the player window (where the time played is viewing) which will create a Genius playlist off that song. It does **not** show the list of songs in the Genius Mix but is a Genius playlist made from that song. It does however give you the list to rate the song. The other alternative is to search for the song in your Music library.

Until Apple fixes this bug, I suggest filing a bug either at Apple's [Bug Reporter](http://bugreporter.apple.com) (requires a free ADC account) or Apple's [Feedback page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html) for iTunes. The Bug Reporter tends to get better results however.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GrowlTunes for the Mac, a similar utility workaround for Windows utility is  [iTunesKeys](http://www.mattberube.com/software/iTunesKeys/).

It provides the ability to assign universal keyboard combinations of your choosing to each star rating, plus a few other basic iTunes controls, even if iTunes is not the app with focus.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is simply right-clicking on the iTunes app in the dock while the song is playing, and change the rating there. No extra software or playlists necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPhone or iPod touch you can use Apple's free remote app to connect to your mac's iTunes and change the rating from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like GrowlTunes is you are using Growl.  Thats how I rate all my music with iTunes in the backround.